# Is it possible to write express app and native firebase functions together?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this structure for my file and folders.

```
.
└── src/
    ├── index.ts
    ├── auth/
    │   └── auth.ts
    ├── controllers/
    │   ├── user.ts
    │   └── event.ts
    ├── functions/
    │   └── email.ts
    └── models/
        ├── user-model.ts
        ├── event-model.ts
        └── email-model.ts
```

index.ts contains this.

```
    import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
    admin.initializeApp();
    admin.firestore().settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
    
    module.exports = {
      ...require("./controllers/user"),
      ...require("./controllers/event"),
      ...require("./functions/email"),
    };
```

event.ts and user.ts follow this structure

```
const eventApp: express.Application = express();
eventApp.use(bodyParser.json());
eventApp.use(cors({ origin: true }));
eventApp.get("/",
    isAuthenticated,
    isAuthorized({ hasRole: ["admin"] }),
    async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => { ... });

module.exports.events = functions.https.onRequest(eventApp);
```

email.ts follows this structure

```
module.exports.sendInitialInvitation = functions.firestore
.document('{collection}/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot, context: any) => { ... });
```

One thing to note here is that I'm trying to mix firebase functions with express app.

When I try to deploy this I keep getting an error which I keep trying to figure out what it is and why this is happening.

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it from their experience dealing with this? Let me know if you have any questions. Would appreciate the help.

p.s. It deploys fine when I delete `functions` folder and content as well as remove the reference from index.ts file.

Comment: Did you have a requirement which has the use of firestore document to be used in the express app ? if so then entire app should be deployed as singular function and if not then you can deploy them as individual like you are doing but instead of exporting your controller use them with like `eventApp.use('/user', userController);` respectively. Take a look at [this example](https://codefile.io/f/Kj3nVD3AoQKPOF8AQEAZ)

Comment: Hi does my posted comment solve your issue ? If so I will post as an answer so that community members will also get the answer.

Comment: Hey, @RohitKharche thank you for your reply. I was able to follow document below to help me unblock. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions

This has great resource to modularize your application. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: If that solves your issue please post an answer so other community members also get precise answer for this type problem.